# Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM, how to set error page for non-existing php file

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, custom-error-pages

I'm currently using Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM, everything works fine except for getting the error page for non-existing php files:

If there is a request for a non-existing php file, then I would get a response "File not found.". But what I want is to redirect that request to our error page.

Because all the php request will first go to php_fpm, so the php default error page mechanism would not work.

I tried some mod_rewrite things, but it did not work either:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ /path/to/404.html [R=404,L]

ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/file/
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please show the errors you're receiving.

Comment: Say there is a sample page www.test.com. And there is no test.php there.                                                   If we go www.test.com/test.php, it would display file not found(handled by the php-fpm) instead of the error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by adding:

```
ProxyErrorOverride on
```